# GCC conversion warning when assigning to a bitfield

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

Is there any way to supress the warning generated by gcc in this code:

```
int main() {
    struct flagstruct {
        unsigned flag : 1;
    } a,b,c;

    a.flag = b.flag | c.flag;

    return a.flag;
}
```

The warning is

```
warning: conversion to 'unsigned char:1' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

It looks like the the two flags are extended to int when ored together.
What I think is really strange is that casting any of the two flags to unsigned supresses the warning.

```
a.flag = (unsigned)b.flag | c.flag;
```

Is this a compiler bug or is it supposed to work this way?

Comment: Please give `gcc` version.

Comment: Pick your favorite. They all generate the warning when compiled with `-Wconversion`

Comment: I would expect warnings about using variables (the 3 single bit definitions a,b,c) that have not been set to a value.

Comment: @user3629249 true, but not the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one year I revised the issue:

Just tested again with different compiler versions. When I first ran into this bug (now I am quite sure, I am allowed to call it a bug), I already realized the warning existed only in clang < 3.1 and all GCC versions at that time. The warning is still produced by all GCC versions < 5.

Since there is no other way to silence the error, the only solution is to update to GCC > 5 or add the unsigned cast `a.flag = (unsigned)b.flag | c.flag;`.

Answer (score 7):

> It looks like the the two flags are extended to int when ored together.

This is *integer promotion* and it is defined in the strangely worded clause 6.3.1.1:2 of the C99 standard:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> …
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int. If an
>   int can represent all values of the original type, the value is
>   converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.
>   These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged
>   by the integer promotions.

First, the processor does not compute directly on bit-fields, and may also not have instructions to compute on the narrower integer types `char` and `short`. The C standard captures this by having arithmetic operations defined only on `int`, `unsigned int` and wider integer types. Where the standard says “may be used” above, it is trying (poorly) to express that **all** short types and bit-fields must be promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` before participating in arithmetic.

Second, all unsigned bit-fields that are not wide enough to include values that cannot be represented as `int` are promoted to `int`.
In other words, GCC is behaving according to the standard by promoting your unsigned bit-field into a signed `int`, and adding an explicit cast, as you did, seems the best policy against bad surprises in the future (and against the warning).

> What I think is really strange is that casting any of the two flags to unsigned supresses the warning.

*Usual arithmetic conversions*, another interesting concept in the C standard (6.3.1.8 in C99), have for consequence that if any of the two operands is explicitly converted to an `unsigned int`, then the other operand is also, implicitly this time, converted to `unsigned int` and the `|` operation is an `unsigned int` operation producing an `unsigned int` result.

In other words, `(unsigned)b.flag | c.flag` is strictly equivalent to `(unsigned)b.flag | (unsigned)c.flag`. In this case the compiler considers that there is no reason for to warn about the assignment, since the result of the computation is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is still think it is a compiler bug. The standard doesn't tell compiler writes when to emit warnings. So the compiler can know for sure, that no precision is lost in the assignment. The assignemnt 1-bit-bitfield = 32-bit-unsigned; is loosing precision as well and no warning there...

Comment: I just tried all compilers available on http://gcc.godbolt.org/. Most of them produce a warning, except clang>=3.2. clang-3.0 does produce this warning. So clang seems to agree with me, that it is in fact a compiler bug. The weirdest thing are the messages generated by all avialable gcc/g++ versions: `warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char:1’ from ‘unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]`. Adding the cast to unsigned to the first flag removes the warning. Casting an unsigend to unsigned removes a warning?!

Answer (score 4):

The best way to solve this warning is to explicitly acknowledge you do not need the excess bits:

> a.flag = (b.flag | c.flag) & 0x00000001;

I'm currently using *arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.4.1 20160609 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 237715]*, and this is the only consistent way to get rid of them.

Can't comment on why explicit casting to `(unsigned)` solves this in the case you posted, though. Peculiar at best, and I doubt whether you will be as lucky under other circumstances, too.

Comment: @M.M No, I didn't. Seems a bit odd, too. That can only work in case your bitfield is just 1 bit wide. It is not a consistent way to get rid of the warnings arising from using bitfields. Of course, you must mask the value you want to store according to your bitfield size, i.e. & 0x00000003 for 2 bits, etc.

Comment: This is ugly and error prone as pravus already stated. If you change the bit-size of your bitfield member, you have to change all masks as well (Surely you could use a macro or a constant, but it is still ugly). The compiler should be smart enough to figure it out on it's own.
Just tested GCC >= 5.1: The warning is not shown anymore -> Looks like it really was a compiler bug