# Son of GCC conversion warning when assigning to a bitfield

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am trying to solve almost the exact same problem as [GCC conversion warning when assigning to a bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480059/gcc-conversion-warning-when-assigning-to-a-bitfield) except none of the solutions appear to work.  As with the linked problem, gcc version does not appear to help, gccs 10.1, 9.1, 8.2, 8.1, 7.1, 6.1, 5.1, and 4.9.1 all fail.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
struct foo { uint a:8; uint b:24; };
void bar(struct foo num, uint x) {
    num.b = (5U << 1) | (1 & 1);
    num.b = ((uint)(((5U << 1) | (uint)((uint) x & 1))) & 0xffffffU);
    num.a = (unsigned char)x;
}
```

[Watch it fail on Godbolt.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xFt_jg) The compiler produces:

```
In function 'bar':
5:13: error: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int:24' may change value [-Werror=conversion]
    5 |     num.b = ((uint)(((5U << 1) | (uint)((uint) x & 1))) & 0xffffffU);
      |             ^
```

As you can see, I tried explicitly masking to 24 bits, casting random things to unsigned int, and pretty much all combinations of the above (e.g. just masking, just casting, casting in seemingly any relevant location, etc).  The first num.b assignment works with constants, but adding the variable messes everything up.

I've worked around the problem through pragmas as below, but that is not a very satisfying solution.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
    num.b = (5U << 1) | (x & 1U);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

@Artyr came up with a solution in a comment to the question.  I'll accept it if he turns it into an answer.  However, when investigating that solution I discovered another way to solve the problem which **really** doesn't make sense.  In the example below, only the last assignment fails.

```
uint z = 5U;
num.b = (5U << 1) | (1 & 1); //OK
num.b = ((z << 1) | (x & 1)) & 0xffffffU; //OK
num.b = ((5U << 1) | (x & 1)) & 0xffffffU; //BAD
```

What I don't understand is why adding another variable z which is statically assigned from the same constant fixes the problem.  Why does the combination of a constant and a variable cause the problem?

Comment: You seem to be making your own trouble.  I had difficulty reproducing this with GCC 8.3.1: compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` did not emit the conversion warning you present.  The reason is, apparently, that that warning *is not included* among any of those warning groups.  I reproduced the issue only when I specifically requested `-Wconversion` or `-Werror=conversion`.  So don't do that.  That the warning is not included in any of the aforementioned groups is a good sign that it is meant only for special purposes.

Comment: Is `1` treated the same way as `1u`?

Comment: @ryyker, `1` has type `int`, whereas `1u` has type `unsigned int`, but that doesn't actually make any difference as used in the OP's code.

Comment: `num->b = (5U << 1) | (_Bool)(x & 1);` seems to fix it. `num->b = x & 1 ? 10 : 11` also works, but this obviously doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Fair suggestion, but I actually found a surprising number of bugs in this particular codebase with `-Wconversion` including in code generated by a vendor tool.  99.9% stupid, but the .1% was valuable.

Comment: What is the idea behind this convoluted expression for `num.b = ` ?  I guess you intended some simpler formula and added mangling to try and dodge the warning, but it's not clear what the original intent was

Comment: @M.M: I literally want:  `num->b = (VERSION << 1) | (flag & 1);` Everything else is just trying to avoid the warning.  (Where #define VERSION 5).

Comment: `(VERSION << 1) + !!(flag & 1)` works for me (assuming VERSION is a preprocessor macro for `5u`)

Comment: @M.M It's most likely coming from a macro.

Comment: You most likely run into a bug in GCC's implementation of `-Wconversion`. In case it reproduces in the latest GCC you can file a bug in [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) (if it does not, it means it's been fixed). For now your only choice is to work around this by disabling `-Wconversion` for this specific file via pragmas or in Makefile.

Comment: @yugr: [Bug 95213](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95213) files based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it'll result in a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any answers for me to accept after a day, I'll summarize the discoveries from the comments.

- @Artyer discovered that casting the variable to a Boolean fixes the problem.  This fixes the tactical problem but does not solve the more general problem (e.g. `z & 0xf`).

  ```
  num->b = (5U << 1) | (_Bool)(x & 1);
  ```
- @M.M independently discovered what I assume results in the same effect (conversion to Boolean).  Using `!!` makes the problem go away.  Again, this fixes the tactical problem but does not solve the more general problem (e.g. `z & 0xf`).

  ```
  num->b = (5U << 1) | !!(x & 1);
  ```
- I discovered, while investigating the above solutions, that storing the "constant" side of the expression into a variable works around the problem generally.

  ```
  unsigned int z = 5U;
  num->b = (z << 1) | (x & 1);
  ```
- @yugr believes that this is a bug.  [Bug 95213](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95213) opened with gcc to track this.